# Shows the message as ANT Build Successfull,even if the testcases are failed

Tags: selenium, ant, build

I am trying to run a Build.xml using ANT..but even when my testcase fails the build output shows as Build Succesfull,though it shows which test case has been failed please see the below OUPUT:-

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\UC179797\workspace\My_Framework\Build.xml
compile:
[javac] C:\Users\UC179797\workspace\My_Framework\Build.xml:15: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
run:
[testng] [TestNG] Running:
[testng] C:\Users\UC179797\workspace\My_Framework\testng.xml
[testng] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 6722
[testng] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
[testng] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[testng] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[testng] 2
[testng] ===============================================
[testng] Suite
[testng] Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
[testng] ===============================================
[testng] The tests failed.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 50 seconds
```

Jenkins doesnot indicate "red dot" even after the project is failed

Answer (score 3):

The Ant build status (`SUCCESSFUL` or `FAILED`) is not related to the result of the tests. The build status is usually failed when a task has failed for an unexpected reason.

Nevertheless, the output shows that the build.xml uses the [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html) task. There is an attribute to tell `testng` to set a property in case a test has failed. Specifically you can use `failureProperty` and subsequently check if the property is set. If it is set, you can fail the build since you would know that at least one of the tests has failed.

```
<testng ... failureProperty="failed.test.prop" ... />

<fail if="failed.test.prop" message="A test has failed" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment....but just because of this message.i.e "Build SuccessFull" ,My Jenkins is even not indicating the project as failed one i.e in "red dot"

Comment: @Kiran Did you try the `fail` task mentioned in the answer? The whole purpose of this task is to cause the build to fail, i.e. the output would show `BUILD FAILED`.